# Strange HTML doctype error when trying to run Python script from bash

Tags: python, html, bash, wget

I have a bash script which is supposed to call a Python script stored on GitHub and run it with arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash +x

wget https://github.place.otherplace.com/myrepo/repo_folder/blob/Python/pythonScript.py
chmod +x pythonScript.py
python pythonScript.py
```

I'm getting the following response:
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘DisputeSystem.py’

```
 0K .......... .......... .......... ........               795K=0.05s

2016-06-14 11:08:24 (795 KB/s) - ‘pythonScript.py’ saved [39657]

  File "pythonScript.py", line 4
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

I figure it has something to do with wget pulling the HTML headers as well, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to strip them. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

You're not downloading the script. You're downloading a GitHub web page with the script and a whole bunch of other stuff on it, like GitHub navigation and a search bar and clickable line numbers.

Go to that page in your web browser, and you should see a "Raw" link. Click on that, and the resulting page is what you should be `wget`ting.

Comment: I swear to God I copied and pasted the raw link, it's a conspiracy! Thanks for pointing out the obvious!